# Can't unsubscribe from email notifications

Tags: bug, email, email-notification

I tried to unsubscribe from Tips & Reminders, Community Milestones, and Recommanded Jobs unsuccessfully. Below is the relevant screenshot with console errors. Any help would be appreciated. (team@stackoverflow.com directed me here.)

[image]

Comment: You may want to blank out your email in the screenshot.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks, but I'm not overly concerned about it.

Answer (score 0):

Now, it magically got fixed. Thanks to whoever was involved!